# How do you administer 2 different Azure accounts, 2 different Email addresses, is there a way to merge them?

Tags: azure, accounts

I now have 2 Azure accounts and I need to move everything from one to the other.  Is there a method to do this?  The first account will end in 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Open a support ticket - I think they can help